# Ajax GET fails to send specific URL parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm sending a GET request to an ASP.NET API using Ajax that looks like this:

```
FindStores = function (tenant, numberOffset) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: constants.URL_BASE + constants.URL_PATH_GETSTORES,
    data: {
        rowOffset: numberOffset,
        limit: 1000,
        sortingColumnName: "Name",
        sortingDirection: "asc",
        tenantId: tenant,
        term: "*"
    },
    async: false,
    success: function(responseObj) {            
        CreateMarkers(responseObj.data);
        if (responseObj.data.length == 1000) {
            FindStores(tenant, responseObj.offset + 1000);
        }
    },
    error: function(e) {            
        console.log("Failure: api.GetStores.  Response status: " + e.message);            
    }
});
};
```

The request should ultimately look like this: `localhost:16935/mppaevents/v2/stores/azure?tenantId=blah&term=*&rowOffset=0&limit=1000&sortingColumnName=Name&sortingDirection=asc`

However, in the console, my Ajax request is missing my `rowOffset` parameter: `localhost:16935/mppaevents/v2/stores/azure?tenantId=blah&term=*&limit=1000&sortingColumnName=Name&sortingDirection=asc`

I've tried passing both `0` and `10` to the `FindStores()` function to see if it was an issue with sending `0`, which is how I would like to start, but neither worked. I've also tried rearranging the order of the parameters, thinking the wildcard character may be throwing it off, but order seems to make no difference.

For some reason, only the `rowOffset` parameter is missed, and it's missed regardless of the order of the parameters. Any help is very much appreciated in advance; thanks!

EDIT: I've narrowed down the issue: `numberOffset` is coming through as undefined. As per @Dumbledore's suggestion, I built the route with hardcoded URI parameters rather than the data field, and got `localhost:16935/mppaevents/v2/stores/azure?tenantId=blah&term=*&rowOffset=undefined&limit=1000&sortingColumnName=Name&sortingDirection=asc`. I've tried calling it two ways:

`FindStores(tenant, 0)` and `var offset = 0; FindStores(tenant, offset)`. Both offset values go to my function call as `undefined`

Comment: Cannot reproduce at jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1tmpqojg/

Comment: have you tried changing `rowOffset: numberOffset` to some constant, like `rowOffset: '0'`?  Also, have you tried changing the name of the parameter, like `offset: numberOffset`?

Comment: @SteveH. originally the paramter name was `offset`, which I changed because I didn't know if it was some sort of keyword. I also need it to be dynamic for paging through results from my search.

Comment: As @guest271314 mentions, seems to work with his fiddle.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question; however, you may try to build the URL with the query parameters and skip setting the `data` property.

Comment: @guest271314 Are posts of screenshots allowed? Or links to imgur? Your fiddle doesn't do anything for me when I hit run; what should happen?

Comment: @Mason Try opening `console` at jsfiddle, reviewing `data` option of `$.ajax()` call, which should display `data
:
"rowOffset=0&limit=1000&sortingColumnName=Name&sortingDirection=asc&tenantId=blah&term=*"`

Comment: Ah ok sorry, yes I see now. That only makes me wonder more!

Comment: @Mason Try reproducing at jsfiddle

Comment: @guest271314 barring the different `url` field, my call is exactly the same as yours

Comment: Then should return same results. What is `data` option at `console.log(this)` at your call ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108302/discussion-between-mason-and-guest271314).